# Sonarqube and TFS integration

Tags: sonarqube, tfs-2015

I like to use TFS users as Sonarqube users. Can I integrate them? Currently I'm using Sonarqube 6 and TFS 2013. I can upgrade to TFS 2015 if there is a way in that to do this.

Answer (score 1):

TFS uses Active Directory as its users, so by enabling the Active Directory integration in SonarQube, you'd be golden.

You need to [configure a plugin in SonarQube to enable Active Directory Integration](http://docs.sonarqube.org/display/PLUG/LDAP+Plugin).